# "tracing" version of readlink(1)

Tags: linux, command-line, utility, symlink-traversal

I would like a version of "readlink -f" that provides a trace of every individual symlink resolution it performs.  Something like:

```
$ linktrace /usr/lib64/sendmail
/usr/lib64 -> lib
/usr/lib/sendmail -> ../sbin/sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail
$
```

I know I have used this utility in the past, on linux, and also remember at the time thinking "the name of this tool is completely unintuitive and I will forget it".  Well, that day has arrived.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but there's a libc function `realpath` and a GNU tool of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOBODY WINS. The correct answer is "namei".

Answer (score 0):

[This Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/115856/how-to-list-symbolic-link-chains/115876#115876) (in Bash) may be helpful (although it does not claim to be handling all edge cases).

Comment: Similar to Ben Jackson's attempt, these scripts only resolve the last symlink in the path, and not any "directory-level" symlinks earlier.  "chain /usr/lib64/sendmail" prints only "/usr/lib64/sendmail -> ../sbin/sendmail" which is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Code golf anyone?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;
my $g;
my $f = shift;
while (1) {
    print $f;
    $g = readlink($f);
    last unless defined $g;
    printf " -> %s\n", $g;
    $f =~ s,/[^/]*$,,;
    $f = File::Spec->rel2abs($g, $f);
}
print "\n";
```

Ok, how about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;

sub r {
    my ($p, $s) = @_;
    my $l = readlink $p;
    if ($l) {
        printf "%s -> %s\n", $p, $l;
        $p =~ s,/[^/]*$,,;
        r("",File::Spec->rel2abs($l,$p) . $s)
    } else {
        $s =~ s!^(/?[^/]+)(.*)! r($p.$1, $2) !e;
    }
}
r("",shift);
```

The output is not quite as described but it's understandable.  And dig that craaazy recursive executable regexp substitution!

Comment: Doesn't handle the /usr/lib64 -> /usr/lib step.

Comment: I specifically added code (rel2abs) to handle that case and tested it.  Not sure what you mean...

Comment: /usr/lib64 is also a symlink.  It points to /usr/lib.  It needs to be resolved as part of resolving any path beginning with it.  Your script resolves the end symlink only.  The final result of "linktrace.BenJ /usr/lib64/sendmail" is "/usr/lib64/../sbin/sendmail" which is not sufficient.

Comment: On most systems, `/usr/lib64` is not a symlink, though. (Yes, there are some distros around that do this weird stuff. According to https://features.opensuse.org/308372 though, that's against standards.)